# Slicing key-value pairs from a hash of hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I'm doing some work with AppConfig, but for convenience, I want the array of options to have another data element (here called `'SWITCH'`) to it.

The typical input to AppConfig's `define()` function is a list of (string, hashref) pairs, eg

```
    "cfg" => { ALIAS => 'c',ARGS => "=s"},
```

Now, for ease of maintaining a very long list of configuration options, I have extended this with a new key (call it "`SWITCH`") that I use for housekeeping during the execution of the program, well after the arguments are processed.
Example:

```
source => { 
SWITCH => '/File',
ALIAS => "file",
ARGS => "=s",
},
```

AppConfig does not like this, of course, and generates an error if it encounters the `SWITCH` key. So before I pass the list of options to `define()` I need to slice out `SWITCH` and its value for each option.

Following the previous example, the result would be:

```
source => { 
ALIAS => "file",
ARGS => "=s",
},
```

I had some code like this (`%qcfg` is a hash containing the options list for `define()`; yes, I know AppConfig treats it as a list, but it's easier to work with as a hash, and then flatten it to a list when passing it to `define()`):

```
my %newcfg = map {
    my $hashref = $qcfg{$_};
    $_ => +{map ($_ => $hashref->{$_}, grep (!/^SWITCH$/, keys %{$hashref}))}
} keys %qcfg;
```

But %newcfg comes out as a jumbled up mess, so I'm not getting this right. How to get it to manipulate the hashes correctly?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Could you give a better example?

Answer (score 0):

I changed your line from:

```
$_ => +{map ($_ => $hashref->{$_}, grep (!/^SWITCH$/, keys %{$hashref}))}
```

to:

```
$_ => +{ map {$_ => $hashref->{$_}} grep (!/^SWITCH$/, keys %{$hashref}) }
```

I've run it and it seems to work - what do you think?

Comment: Yes, that does work. Thank you. The supplementary question is why does using a block work, but using and expr does not?

Comment: This is ripped from perldoc: " %hash = map +( lc($_) => 1 ), @ array # this is EXPR and works! " - looks like you need brackets around it if you want to use EXPR. @mikb

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to make a copy and remove unwanted keys

```
use Storable qw(dclone);

my %newcfg = %{ dclone(\%qcfg) };           ## make a deep copy
for(keys %newcfg){
     delete $newcfg{$_}{SWITCH}             ## remode SWITCH
}
```

(untested!)